# Facebook for developers - Facebook Login Integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I can't enable the Facebook Login for my new Android App.

I follow the QuickStart settings a few times but it keeps showing me this alert:

[image]

I copied the settings from another app made in the past with Facebook Login enabled, I insert the Development and Release Key Hashes and wrote the correct app name. But I still view the facebook Login (and analytics ) disabled:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**:
My settings page:

[image]

Comment: So what happens when you click “Finish Setup” next to those two products then …?

Comment: When I click "Finish set up" it redirects me to the QuickStart settings page, where I already configure my App.

Comment: And when you go directly via Products -> {product} -> Settings?

Comment: I also configure the Products -> {product} -> Settings page. I edit the question with a screen shot of the page

Comment: can you add quick start page screenshots as well

Comment: @AmanRawat in the quickstart page I choose Android, wrote the Package Name and the Default Activity Class Name of my app,  and then instert the Development and Releas key Hashes

Comment: rather than coping settings from another app.. try creating from the scratch because it may not be updating your package name with the right keys. could be some minor issue, but give a try.